# How do I get my Div2 to be directly below my Div1

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is my code. I would like it to not be hard coded dimensions so that it will work on different browser resoultions (not sure if that is the correct terminology) Thank you very much in advance.

```css
#div1 {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: cyan;
  font-family: "Arial Black", Gadget, sans-serif;
  font-size: 24px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 300px;
  border: 25px solid red;
  padding: 25px;
  top: 30%;
  left: 50%;
  margin: -100px 0 0 -150px;
}
#div2 {
  background-color: cyan;
  font-family: "Arial Black", Gadget, sans-serif;
  font-size: 24px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 300px;
  border: 25px solid orange;
  padding: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1">Greeting Card Generator</div>
<div id="div2">Content Goes Here</div>
```

Comment: What you're looking for is responsive or adaptive design: https://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-responsive-and-adaptive-design/. But as of now your question is too broad because we don't know exactly what you're wanting it to look like.

Comment: Is this what you want? https://jsfiddle.net/xpuooebr/

Comment: Yes but I wanted it to not span across the entire width of the screen.

Answer (score 1):

You just have to remove some properties of **#div1**, your CSS for #div1 will be,

```
#div1 {
  background-color: cyan;
  font-family: "Arial Black", Gadget, sans-serif;
  font-size: 24px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 300px;
  border: 25px solid red;
  padding: 25px;
}
```

[Check this fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/p69yq1np/)

Answer (score 0):

Have you even considered bootstrap? It makes your life a lot easier.

anyways here you go:

```
    #div1{

        background-color: cyan;
        font-family: "Arial Black", Gadget, sans-serif;
        font-size: 24px;
        text-align: center;
        width: 300px;
        border: 25px solid red;
        padding: 25px;



    }
    #div2{

        background-color: cyan;
        font-family: "Arial Black", Gadget, sans-serif;
        font-size: 24px;
        text-align: center;
        width: 300px;
        border: 25px solid orange;
        padding: 25px;
    }
```